# Running Django runserver doesn't respond on the browser

Tags: python, django, server

I've create a project in a server with CentOS, Django 1.10.1 and using python 3.5.

When I run in the terminal py manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 it shows

> Performing system checks...
>
> System check identified no issues (0 silenced). December 10, 2017 -
>   15:45:23 Django version 1.10.1, using settings 'samplepy35.settings'
>   Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/ Quit the server
>   with CONTROL-C.

When I use the command `netstat -tuplen` it says that python is listening on PORT 8000.

But when I try to access on the browser it doesn't respond.

What can the problem be?

Comment: how are you running it in the browser?? what address are you accessing?

Comment: My server IP address in the port 8000

Comment: you need to type python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0 then access http://ip:8000

Comment: this is what I'm doing

Comment: you said you are typing 0.0.0.0:8000 in the terminal

Comment: Yes. I'm typing 0.0.0.0:8000 and then accessing <my ip>:8000

Comment: no, you dont need to mention the port like that, just type python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0 then access ip:8000

Comment: It says: CommandError: "0.0.0.0" is not a valid port number or address:port pair.

Comment: sorry python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0 8000 is what you need to run in the terminal